# Logo not responsive Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Something is preventing my logo from being responsive. I have all the correct tags I think...

```
<div id="row" class="image-responsive">
<a href="default.asp"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Top Jocks" border="0"></a>
</div>
```

In [overstyle.css](http://www.topjocks.co.za/overstyle.css):

```
#logo {
  max-width:100%;
}
#logo img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

[Page with the problem](http://www.topjocks.co.za/default2.asp).

Thanks in advance.
Dave

Comment: `class="image-responsive"` should be applied to `img` tag

Comment: I can't find an id `logo` on your page. Additionally the width of the image just needs to be set to 100%

Answer (score 0):

1. As mentioned in the comments, [the `.img-responsive` class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive) should be applied to the image itself.

   > Images in Bootstrap 3 can be made responsive-friendly via the addition of the `.img-responsive` class. This applies `max-width: 100%;`, `height: auto;` and `display: block;` to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element.
2. The [bootstrap.css](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css) already contains the instruction `img { border: 0; }`.

So try to use

```
<a href="default.asp"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo.png" alt="Top Jocks"></a>
```

instead of

```
<div id="row" class="image-responsive">
<a href="default.asp"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Top Jocks" border="0"></a>
</div>
```

If my solution works as it should, you can remove this code from [overstyle.css](http://www.topjocks.co.za/overstyle.css):

```
#logo {
  max-width:100%;
}
#logo img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Bootstrap then use class

> img-responsive

Or else give css property to your logo image or class,

```
img {
 width:100%;
 max-width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add class `img-responsive` in `img` tag.

```
<img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Top Jocks" border="0">
```